# Azure Devops schedule deployment task pickup last deployed build instate of new one

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am facing an issue with the deployment schedule trigger in the Azure DevOps server. I have a scheduled build at 12PM every day and the scheduled will be trigger on time.

But, the issue is when I do manually deployment in day DevOps server not overwrite manually deployment it's not deploying latest it is redeploying previous code, not the latest.

Please check the schedule and deployment queue setting.

[image: devops screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of scheduled trigger on release pipeline:

1. [Scheduled release triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#scheduled-release-triggers): Triggers a new release at specific
   times.

   If you want to trigger a release at a specific time instead of every
   build triggers a release, you can use the **Scheduled release triggers**
   and disable [Continuous deployment triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#continuous-deployment-triggers). With this way, by
   default the scheduled release will **always use the latest build
   artifacts** for deployments.

   In addition, if you have enabled the option "**Only schedule releases
   if the source or pipeline has changed**", after previous scheduled
   release, the release will be triggered at the specific times only
   when the source or the pipeline definition has updated. Otherwise,
   the release will not be triggered even if the specific times reach.
   If you want the scheduled release will be always triggered at the
   specific times, you can disable this option.

   [image]
2. [Scheduled stage triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#stage-triggers): Trigger a new deployment to the stage at a
   specific time, after a new release is triggered (`After release`), or
   the dependent previous stages are completed (`After stage`) in the
   release.

   When the scheduled deployment to the stage is triggered at the
   specific time, the deployment will **use the build artifacts that
   triggered the current release**, **not** always the latest build
   artifacts.

So you need to use the first scheduled trigger in release pipeline.